# Precision and Recall of documents equation

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, precision-recall

Hey I understand both the precision and recall equations, I'm just getting confused with this question and how to workout the figures for each TP, TN, FP and FN.

An information retrieval system returns 8 relevant documents and 10 non-relevant documents. There are a total of 20 relevant documents in the collection. What is the precision of the system on this search, what is its recall and what is its F-measure?

Help would be great, thanks!

Comment: First, what do you think they are, based on your understanding so far?

Comment: 8 true positives, 0 true negatives, 0 false positives, 10 false negatives?

Comment: The number of 'positives' has to add up to 18, the number of docs selected, for example, so not quite I think. Precision is % returned docs that were relevant; recall is % of relevant docs that were returned.

Comment: I'm really confused with the wording of the question. Is it saying there are 20 documents, all relevant and none that are non-relevant?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about IR theory.

Answer (score 1):

Precision = relevant returned / total returned = 8 / 18 or about 0.44

Recall = relevant returned / total relevant = 8 / 20 = 0.4

F1 score = 2 * ((precision * recall) / (precision + recall)) or about 0.42

TP = 8 relevant returned documents, FP = 10 non-relevant returned documents

FN = 20 relevant documents - 8 relevant returned documents = 12 relevant documents that were not returned

TN needs the total number of documents in the collection to be computed.